# Alert Dialog shows multiple times On device shake Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-alertdialog

I am creating an app where an alert Dialog is shown when the device is shaken. I have a common method for displaying the dialog box which I am calling from another method as well as when the device is shaken (not at the same time though). So when I call the display dialog method from the other method, the dialog shows properly and dismisses too. Only when the show dislog method is called from the onShake() , it is shown twice, sometimes even more.

This is my code:-

```
@Override
    public void onShake(float force) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        date =  cal.getTime();
        timeString =  sdf.format(date);


        showDialog(timeString, "Confirm ");
        if(alert!=null && !alert.isShowing())
        {
            alert.show();
        }

    }

public void showDialog(String timeString, String title)
    {

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(title);
        String timeString1 = timeString.split("T")[1];
        builder.setMessage("Reaching at:"+" "+ timeString1+"?");

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing

            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog

                new AddStatusTask().execute();

            }

        });

        alert =  builder.create();

    }


private class AddStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        String AddedResult;
        ProgressDialog pd;
        //Get Value of accessToken

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setMessage("Updating..");
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Some code;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Sorry"))
            {

                pd.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not update. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            if(pd!=null &&pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.setMessage("Updated");


                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Please put a log in onShake(). See how many times log is printing in onShake().I am sure it is calling multiple times. Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @Vivek how do I restrict the shake to be available only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's natural to be shown multiple times, to control it use a boolean and set it to false for initialize and when the dialog is shown set it to true and when it is dismissed set it to false again. As for controlling every time you want to show the dialog check the value of this boolean to make sure that one instance of it is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am just giving the sample code. Please change it accordingly.

```
private boolean bool=true;

        @Override
        public void onShake(float force) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(bool)
            {
                bool=false;
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                date =  cal.getTime();
                timeString =  sdf.format(date);


                showDialog(timeString, "Confirm ");
                if(alert!=null && !alert.isShowing())
                {
                    alert.show();
                }
            }

        }
```

After dialog work is finished. Make to bool variable true for next shake. If you have any query please let me know.